# JavaScript variable undefined after assigning value inside a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
 var currentURL;
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    currentURL = tabs[0].url;
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);
    console.log(currentURL);
  });
  console.log(currentURL);
```

The above code is supposed to assign the URL of current page to variable "currentURL", however, the console log inside the function logs the correct value, while the one outside the function logs "undefined".

I cannot figure out why "currentURL" 's value is undefined outside the function, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chrome.tabs.query()` method is asynchronous. Therefore, the value of `currentURL` is not yet defined when the last line is run.

Looking into async/await functions should help you code your program to wait for the callback to resolve before it moves on further.

Comment: thank you very much, my problem is solved

Comment: Of course @RyanDeng! Keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

The callback is async and that’s why you can’t rely on the outer console.log. The outer log happens before the async callback which is still waiting in the event queue. After outer log happens, the callback is processed and so you can successfully log the tabs value inside that callback only.

Refer this documentation for more insights:-
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#sync-example

Answer (score 0):

```
     var currentURL; // executed first
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }// executed second
, function (tabs) { // -> executed fourth
        currentURL = tabs[0].url;
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);
        console.log(currentURL);
      });
      console.log(currentURL);// executed third
```

Pay attention that the function inside `chrome.tabs.query` is a callback. That means it will be launched after the console log you wrote outside. That's why the value in your `console.log` is still undefined